# How to add a link to menu before WPML output?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I would like to add a link to a menu programatically. This is simplified version of my code and it works, but WPML adds its language selector on the last place. How can I add my link before WPML output? 
`$items` is just a string with all HTML

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_to_nav', 1, 2 );
function add_search_to_nav( $items, $args ) {

    $items .= '<li><a href="#">Something</a></li>';
    return $items;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the like as below:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_to_nav', 10, 2 );
function add_search_to_nav( $items, $args ) {
    $items_array = array();
    while ( false !== ( $item_pos = strpos ( $items, '<li', 3 ) ) ) {
        $items_array[] = substr($items, 0, $item_pos);
        $items = substr($items, $item_pos);
    }
    $items_array[] = $items;
    $new_item = '<li><a href="#">Something</a></li>';

    array_splice($items_array, $args->menu->count, 0, $new_item); 

    $items = implode('', $items_array);

    return $items;
}
```

Here `$args->menu->count` provides the count of menu item without WPML language switcher.